# Как в place записать содержимое поля input?

Tags: input, html, теги

На странице есть `div` с тегом `place=""`. Как в этот `Place` записать содержимое поля `input`?

Или наоборот - получить `place`'ом содержимое `input`'а (если это возможно).

Comment: Вячеслав, старайтесь правильно писать впоросы! Что означает   " есть div с тегом place=""  "   что за тег Place ?

Comment: <div class="" place=""></div>
Что-то вроде этого...

Comment: @Вячеслав `place` - это аттрибут в таком случае.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде:

```js
$("#place").change(function(e) {
  $("div[place]").attr("place", e.target.value);
});

$("#getPlace").click(function() {
  let placeValue = $("div[place]").attr("place");
  console.log(placeValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="place" type="text" />
<div place=""></div>

<button id="getPlace">Получить place</button>
```

Comment: В общем-то, что-то похожее, но у меня почему-то не работает (тестил на w3schools). Что я не так делаю?
https://codeshare.io/a3DN34

Comment: Кстати, забыл сказать, что класс div'а тоже надо упомянуть. А то их много. И все - с Place'ами.